# How to use array in getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I used an ajax function to fetch labels and ids from the database, which contains exactly the same set of ids used in my form. The query returned a comma separated value which I sent to a second function as below.

This function successfully split the comma separated values, and I used it to build an array of id tags.

Now all I want is to feed these id tags into and arrayed variable and use it to fetch the values of the forms so submitted.

Please can someone help. Below is the second function to fetch the values from the form and alert them as it does:

```
function call_update(params){

var pValues=new array();

newParams=params.split(',');

  for(i=0;i<newParams.length;i++){

    pValues[i] = document.getElementById(newParams[i]).value;

    alert(newParams[i] +" is "+pValues[i]);

  }
}
```

---

### This is an excerpt of the form generated

```
<form action="#" name="continuation" id="continuation" class="form-horizontal">
                           <div class="form-wizard">
                              <div class="navbar steps">
                                 <div class="navbar-inner">
                                    <ul class="row-fluid">
                                       <li class="span2">
                                          <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="step active">
                                          <span class="number">1</span>
                                          <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i>Statistics</span>   
                                          </a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="span2">
                                          <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                                          <span class="number">2</span>
                                          <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Personal Intro</span>   
                                          </a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="span2">
                                          <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                                          <span class="number">3</span>
                                          <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Resume</span>   
                                          </a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="span2">
                                          <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                                          <span class="number">4</span>
                                          <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Experience</span>   
                                          </a> 
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="span2">
                                          <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                                          <span class="number">5</span>
                                          <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Availability</span>   
                                          </a> 
                                       </li>

                                       <li class="span2">
                                          <a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                                          <span class="number">6</span>
                                          <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Photo Book</span>   
                                          </a> 
                                       </li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div id="bar" class="progress progress-success progress-striped">
                                 <div class="bar"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tab-content">
                                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                                   <fieldset><legend>Personal Information</legend>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                                       <div class="controls">
                                          <input type="text" value="jamehex" class="span6 m-wrap" tabindex="1" readonly/>
                                          <span class="help-inline">Username generated from your email address</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Birthday</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input class="span6 m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker" size="16" value="04-11-2013" type="text"></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Bra Size</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Bra_Size" id="Bra_Size" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Bust</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Bust" id="Bust" class="span6 m-wrap" /><span class="help-inline">Enter Size in Inches</span></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Dress Size</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Dress_Size" id="Dress_Size" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Ethnic Look</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Ethnic_Look" id="Ethnic_Look" class="span6 m-wrap" /><span class="help-inline">Choose Your Ethnic Group</span></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Eye Color</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Eye_Color" id="Eye_Color" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Hair Color</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Hair_Color" id="Hair_Color" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Hair Length</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Hair_Length" id="Hair_Length" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Height</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Height" id="Height" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Hips</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Hips" id="Hips" class="span6 m-wrap" /><span class="help-inline">Enter Size in Inches</span></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Other</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Other" id="Other" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Personal Site</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Personal_Site" id="Personal_Site" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Physique</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Physique" id="Physique" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Piercings</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Piercings" id="Piercings" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Shoe Size</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Shoe_Size" id="Shoe_Size" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Skin Color</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Skin_Color" id="Skin_Color" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Waist</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Waist" id="Waist" class="span6 m-wrap" /><span class="help-inline">Enter Size in Inches</span></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Weight</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Weight" id="Weight" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div>                                    
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset><legend>Details</legend>
                                   <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Acting Union</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Acting_Union" id="Acting_Union" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">In-Person Castings</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="In-Person_Castings" id="In-Person_Castings" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Model Agency</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Model_Agency" id="Model_Agency" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Objections</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Objections" id="Objections" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Paid Work</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Paid_Work" id="Paid_Work" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Pro Status</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Pro_Status" id="Pro_Status" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Talent Agency</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Talent_Agency" id="Talent_Agency" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Time for Prints</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Time_for_Prints" id="Time_for_Prints" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div>                                    
                                    </fieldset>
                                     <fieldset><legend>Location</legend>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Country" id="Country" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Nearest City 1</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Nearest_City_1" id="Nearest_City_1" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Nearest City 2</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Nearest_City_2" id="Nearest_City_2" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Nearest City 3</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Nearest_City_3" id="Nearest_City_3" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">State</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="State" id="State" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div>                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset><legend>Travel</legend>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Africa</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Africa" id="Africa" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Asia</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Asia" id="Asia" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Europe</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Europe" id="Europe" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">North America</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="North_America" id="North_America" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">South America</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="South_America" id="South_America" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div>                                    </fieldset>
                                     <fieldset><legend>Languages</legend>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Dutch</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Dutch" id="Dutch" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">English</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="English" id="English" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">French</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="French" id="French" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Italia</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Italia" id="Italia" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Latino</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Latino" id="Latino" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div><div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Spanish</label>
                                    <div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="Spanish" id="Spanish" class="span6 m-wrap" /></div>
                           </div>                                    </fieldset>
```

---

### This is the ajax function that fetches back the id_tags from the database to match the ids in the form

```
function saveContinue(curr){
    //alert(curr);
//  var x = [ 'p0', 'p1', 'p2' ]; 
//call_me(x);
var findLabel  
    try{
        findLabel = new XMLHttpRequest();}
        catch(e){
            try{
                findLabel = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
                catch(e){
                    try{
                        findLabel = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
                        catch(e){
                            alert("Browser Error");
                            return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    findLabel.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(findLabel.readyState == 4){
                        var test = findLabel.responseText;
                        //alert(test);
                        document.getElementById('wait').style.display="none";
                        call_update(test)
                         return true;

                         }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById('wait').style.display="";
                    }
                    }

                    var queryString="?tab_id=" + curr;
                    findLabel.open("GET","../ajaxHandles/fetchLabel.php" + queryString,true);
                    findLabel.send(null);       

}
```

---

### The fetchLabel.php is as follows

```
<?php
include_once( '../classes/stdPageClass.php' );

$tab_id=$stdObj->escstr($_GET['tab_id']);

exit($stdObj->fetchLabels($tab_id));

?>
```

---

### Here is the public method fetchLabels();

```
public function fetchLabels($tab_id){
          $section_id=$this->getAllByOrder('mc_user_profile_sections','tab_id',$tab_id,'','ASC','id'); //fetching list of involved sections
           $label='';
          sleep(4);
          foreach($section_id as $id)
          $label[]=$this->getAllByOrder('mc_user_profile_fields','section',$id,'label','ASC','label');
          $found='';
          foreach($label as $val){
              if(is_array($val))
                {
                    foreach($val as $lab)
                            $found[]=$lab;
                }
          }
        // //print_r ($found);
         $found=implode(',',$found);
         //exit(json_encode($found,true));
         return $found;

      }
```

---

```
Finally, here is the second ajax function excerpt that is meant to save the form values in the database. For now, I just want it to alert each value
-----------------------------------------

 function call_update(params){
        var pValues = []; //line 1
        var newParams=params.split(',');
        alert(newParams);
        for (i = 0; i < newParams.length; i++) {
            pValues[i] = document.getElementById(newParams[i]).value;
            //alert(newParams[i] + " is " + pValues[i]);
        }
        alert(pValues);
    }
```

---

Please see how this helps you to help me @Siddiqui, @RGraham and others

Comment: it has to be var `pValues=new Array();`

Comment: ..or better: `var pValues = [];`

Comment: And don't forget to add a `var` keyword before `newParams` too, in case you want to use that variable somewhere else.

Comment: you could use JSON as response from server instead of CSV. With that you can get array easily and iterate over it straight away.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Whether you need the rep or not, you should post an answer to stop people just stealing yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you need to change is `Array();` line no 1

try this code

```
function call_update(params){
    var pValues = new Array(); //line 1
    var newParams=params.split(',');
    for(i=0;i<newParams.length;i++){
        pValues[i] = document.getElementById(newParams[i]).value;
        alert(newParams[i] +" is "+pValues[i]);
    }
}
```

Click following link to see the execution

[Execute](http://jsfiddle.net/a8rZx/24/)

Comment: Are your line numbers 0-based and relative to your functions? Cool.

Comment: I have tried this, it didn't make a difference. Also, I added var to newParams as suggested by @RGraham I wouldn't know exactly what the problem is. Please, I'm frustrated right now. Someone please help.

Comment: @user2944292 No idea what's wrong, maybe your input data, but the answer above definitely works: http://jsfiddle.net/Ppjeg/

Comment: I have tested this code in Chrome, IE and FF. Its working fine. Can you show us how you are calling this method?

Comment: @user2944292 I ahve update answer with a link click to see the execution of your code

Comment: Wow, @Siddiqui, that was awesome. Just exactly how I want it. But here is the problem: the form elements are mixtures of input, select and textarea. Even from the link you included in your answer, when I edit it and add select elements, it behaves exactly like mine.

Comment: View that link again.

Comment: `function call_update(params){
    var pValues = new Array(); //line 1   
    var elem = new Array();
    var newParams = params.split(",");

    for(i=0;i<newParams.length;i++){
        elem[i] = document.getElementById(newParams[i]);
       
        if(elem[i].type=="text" || elem[i].type=="textarea"){
            pValues[i] = elem[i].value;
        }else if(elem[i].type=="select-one"){
             pValues[i]= elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value;
        }//else if other elemnts
        alert(newParams[i] +" is "+pValues[i]);
    }
}`

Comment: Cool! Your efforts are simply wonderful. However, I figured out something totally strange. The Birthday field was meant to be filled from a calendar dropdown. Now, when the array pops, the object of the field was showing a null set. This was the source of the Problem. I removed that from the database and everything began to respond perfectly. For Your help, I remain grateful.